# How to save the list obtained from checkbox in django Modelform in databsae

Tags: python, django, modelform

Here, I am trying to save the multiple items checked from my form into the database using django Modelform. I got the list of item using the query but I couldn't save the data. Everything else works fine, the data from other fields are being saved in the database. How can I save these multiple items I got from checkbox?

> models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skills, blank=True, null=True)
    facility = models.ManyToManyField(Facility, blank=True, null=True)
```

> forms.py

```
class AddMyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

> views.py

```
def my_view(request, slug):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddMyModelForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = AddMyModelForm()

    context = {'form': form}

    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

> template

```html
<form action="{% url '...' type.slug %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}

  <h3>Choose the below skills:</h3>

  {% for skill in skills %}

    <input type="checkbox" name="skills" id="skill-{{ skill.id }}" value="{{ skill.id }}">

    <label for="skill-{{ skill.id }}">{{ skill.title }}</label>

  {% endfor %}
  <h3>Choose the facilities below:</h3>
  {% for facility in facilities %}

    <input type="checkbox" name="facility" id="facility-{{ facility.id }}"
           value="{{ facility.id }}">

    <label for="facility-{{ facility.id }}">{{ facility.title }}</label>
  {% endfor %}

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to save the form. Adding `form.save()` before `form.save_m2m()` will be a right thing.

Comment: i used that for the many to many field, it makes no difference

Comment: Yes, you should use both of them together.

Comment: `form.save_m2m()` is not working